# Line breaks are counted as 2 characters in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, charactercount

I have the following code in jQuery that counts the number of characters that have been written in the text box.

The problem is that when inserting line breaks the counter subtracts `2` characters instead of `1``. When a new character is written in the new line the counter is corrected automatically not subtracting any character.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("input", "#textbox", function(event) {
        var character_counter = $(this)[0].innerText.length;
        $("#character-counter").html(160 - character_counter);
  });
});
```

```css
#textbox {
  padding: 6px;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="character-counter">160</div>
```

Comment: `\r\n` default windows line separator

Comment: and `\n` for other OS's

Comment: What is your question overall?

Comment: @Alex I need to know how to do so that when inserting line breaks in the `#textbox` the character counter subtracts `1` and not `2` characters.

Comment: @Smark Whenever you add a new-line, in Windows, two characters get added: `\r\n`, this is why it's being counted as `2` characters. If you get the `keyCode` of the button pressed and check if it was an `Enter` key, you can get rid of it.